# Issue with eclipse: Potential null pointed analysis

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, nullable, notnull

May be, This has been discussed many times. But, I am not clear on how @javax.annotation.nullable and notnull works in Eclipse. I have the below code in eclipse.

```
if(null != getApplicant()){
  name = getApplicant().getName(); //Potential null pointer access
}
```

Wherein, getApplication() is annotated with @Nullable.

In the above code, I have verified against null before accessing it. But, still I get error here by compiler. The same code works fine Intellij. (Most of the developers in my team use this :().

Kindly tell me how can I get this @javax.annotation.Nullable and @javax.annotation.Notnull worked in eclipse in similar way to Intellij. I dont want to change my IDE just for this different behavior.

Answer (score 2):

There's no assurance to the compiler that calling `getApplication()` the second time returns a non-null result as it did the first time. Store it in a local for the test and then use that within the `if` block.

Comment: I do not understand your point here. I have already validated in if condition.. right? Then, why there is no assurance to the complier for the second time. It is the same object, I m trying to access at both the places. Am I missing some thing here?

Comment: No, you validated the first result, and then are using a second result.

Comment: I believe in both the places the result is going to be the same. Then, why is it? Do you mean to say some other thread might alter that object in between these calls? but, it is not static . Please clarify me

Comment: You haven't shown the implementation, but why should *the compiler* think it's the same both times?

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse warns you, that the second method access could potentially return null. Example code to reproduce nullpointer:

```
public class A {
int numberCalls;
Applicant getApplicant() {
if (numberCalls++ > 3)
  return null;
else
  return new Applicant();
}
}
```

I would suggest to implement your call like this:

```
Applicant applicant = getApplicant();
if(null != applicant){
  name = applicant.getName(); //not anymore Potential null pointer access
}
```